# Convergence of series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence given by $$x_n=\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}}}$$
For what values of $\alpha>0,$ $x_n \in l^1.$

I feel for $\alpha>4,$ $x_n\in l^1$ and for other values of $\alpha$ series $\sum |{x_n}|$ diverges.

How to prove it rigorously?

Comment: Why do you feel this?

Comment: where is the series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint : Maybe you know $$x\to 0 \implies (1+x)^k\sim1+kx$$ so you can start from here,$\frac 1n \to x$
$$n\to \infty\\x_n=\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}}}=\sqrt{-1+{(1+\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}})^{\frac12}}}\\\sim \sqrt{-1+{(1+\frac{1}{2n^{\alpha}})}} \\= \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n^{\alpha}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}.\frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}$$ then $for \space \alpha>2,\sum |{x_n}|$ converges

Comment: $\alpha>2$ is enough for the convergence of $\sum |x_n|?$

Comment: @Sameera: Thanks for the true hint, I 'll correct it.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The intuition would be that (using Taylor series)
$$
\sqrt{1+\epsilon} = 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2} - \frac{\epsilon^2}{8} \pm \ldots
 \approx 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
thus
$$
x_n = \sqrt{-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}}}
    \approx \sqrt{-1+\left(1+\frac{1}{2n^{\alpha}}\right)}
    = \frac1{n^{\alpha/2} \sqrt{2}}
$$
as long as $n^\alpha$ is small compared to $1$...

Comment: Do you mean $n^\alpha$ is *large* compared to 1?